# Cropping aerial image using Python?

Tags: python, imagery, lidar, aerial-photography

How can I crop an area from an aerial image knowing the latitude and longitude of the image's corners and also the cropped section?

I have a LiDAR scan and I and want to crop an image overlay to fit over the scanned area.

Comment: Are you using the arcpy or any other spatial python library?

Comment: @evv_gis no i am not, could you recommend one for my situation.

Comment: dklassen below is recommending a very easy to use spatial library in GDAL.  I would go that direction.

Answer (score 3):

You should try using the GDAL library (Python) to clip your raster.  GDAL_translate should work for your needs.  Link below to a similar question.

[[Clipping raster with vector layer using GDAL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16657/clipping-raster-with-vector-layer-using-gdal][1])