# Sentinel-2 Tiles - Find a specific point in the image

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, latitude-longitude, utm, sentinel-2

I am new to the area of Remote Sensing. I am working with the Sentinel-2 data from AWS. I've downloaded [this](http://sentinel-s2-l1c.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/#tiles/30/T/YN/2015/12/3/0/) specific tile and created an RGB GeoTiff. Now, I want to crop the sea in the bottom of the image. First, I get a specific longitude and latitude (here: 42.364456, 0.183105). Since gdalinfo tells me that the coordinate system is "WGS 84 / UTM zone 30N" I converted the longitude and longitude to UTM which results in the zone 31T. But this does not work with the coordinates of the image (it is tile 30T, I already know that the Sentinel tiles are overlapping) How can I solve this problem? Longitude 42.364456 and latitude 0.183105 result in UTM 31T 268039 4694087.

In general: How can I find the exact position (longitude and latitude given) in a tile given like the example here?

Here is the output of `gdalinfo` of the example tile:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: 30_T_YN_2015_12_3.tif
Size is 10980, 10980
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 30N",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-3],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","32630"]]
Origin = (699960.000000000000000,4800000.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (10.000000000000000,-10.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=JPEG
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  699960.000, 4800000.000)
Lower Left  (  699960.000, 4690200.000)
Upper Right (  809760.000, 4800000.000)
Lower Right (  809760.000, 4690200.000)
Center      (  754860.000, 4745100.000)
Band 1 Block=10980x16 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=10980x16 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=10980x16 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

Tile:
[image]

Comment: The easiest way to do this might be to create a vector layer of the lake and then use `gdalwarp` with the `-cutline` options (see [this post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16657/clipping-raster-with-vector-layer-using-gdal)). GDAL will handle the translation between different projections for you in that case.

Comment: Thanks Kersten. However, I need a general solution. I will have a lot of addresses, which will be mapped to their coordinates (longitude and latitude) and then some type of cropping is performed. So I am not really interested in this lake but in a general solution of the problem.  Creating a bounding box which just works for one certain are does not work for me. Sorry for the inaccurateness.

Comment: Clarification: I am (more) interested in mapping the point (given by longitude and latitude) to the right position in the image. Sorry for the inaccurateness.

Comment: I think that you can classify the image (water) and then extract the water polygons. After that you can mask all the lakes from the image.

Comment: Thanks Pau. However, please see my comments above. I am interested in a general solution. How can I find the position in the image which belongs to the given longitude and latitude?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a python script that computes that.

```
from functools import partial
from pprint import pprint

import pyproj
import rasterio

from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.ops import transform

# gdalinfo for sample image returns:
#Size is 10980, 10980
#Corner Coordinates:
#Upper Left  (  600000.000, 9900040.000) ( 56d 6' 4.50"W,  0d54'15.32"S) 
#Lower Left  (  600000.000, 9790240.000) ( 56d 6' 3.14"W,  1d53'51.08"S)
#Upper Right (  709800.000, 9900040.000) ( 55d 6'52.88"W,  0d54'13.95"S)
#Lower Right (  709800.000, 9790240.000) ( 55d 6'50.03"W,  1d53'48.20"S)
#Center      (  654900.000, 9845140.000) ( 55d36'27.64"W,  1d24' 2.33"S)
img = rasterio.open('S2B_21_M_XU_2017_8_23_0_B04.tif')

# We will test with scene center as a point in EPSG 4236 (lat/lon, WGS84)
longitude = -55.60768
latitude = -1.400647
input_coord = Point(longitude, latitude)

to_target_crs = partial(pyproj.transform, pyproj.Proj('+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs '),
                    pyproj.Proj(img.crs))
output_coord = transform(to_target_crs, input_coord)

print "Coord in image projection: %f, %f" % (output_coord.x, output_coord.y)

# Affine transformation from image plain coordinates to image column, line
aff = ~img.transform

print "Column, line in image: %f, %f" % ((output_coord.x, output_coord.y) * aff)
```

Should give you as result:

```
Coord in image projection: 654899.705524, 9845140.101523
Column, line in image: 5489.970552, 5489.989848
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to crop a raster to certain bounds (given in an arbitrary coordinate system like {lat, lon}) is to use [gdal_translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html). You can specify the bounding box using `-projwin` and the coordinate system of that bounding box using `-projwin_srs`.

```
gdal_translate -projwin lon_min lat_max lon_max lat_min -projwin_srs EPSG:4326 \
input_data.tif output_data.tif
```