# Is it possible to clip a shapefile from a raster layer using gdalwarp?

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp

I have a shapefile with a single geometry as the following:

[image]

I also have a GeoTIFF raster that I can put behind this vector layer... I'd like to find a way of programmatically clipping this shapefile feature from my GeoTIFF file, in a way that I get a png image as a result.

The closest solution I found to this problem is [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/28626/173457). This solution solves the problem using `gdalwarp` with the following command line:

```
gdalwarp -of GTiff -cutline area_of_interest.shp -cl area_of_interest  -crop_to_cutline PCE_in_gw.asc  data_masked7.tiff
```

In my case, I only have the Shapefile and the GeoTIFF file. I didn't get what I'm supposed to put on the `.asc` file and the `area_of_interest` parameter in this command line sample. What extra procedures do I have to do to clip my GeoTIFF with a Shapefile while using `gdalwarp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the command line you can do the following:

`gdalwarp -of GTiff -cutline input.shp -crop_to_cutline input.tif input_clip.tif`

Another alternative is with `pkcrop` from [pktools](http://www.nongnu.org/pktools/html/index.html)

`pkcrop -i input.tif -e input.shp -cut -o input_clip.tif`

Answer (score 2):

Look this example in Pyhton and Jupyter Notebook:

```
gdal.Warp(destNameOrDestDS = outputpath, 
          srcDSOrSrcDSTab  = intputpath, 
          cutlineDSName    = shapefile or geojson, 
          cropToCutline    = True,
          copyMetadata     = True,
          dstNodata        = 0)
```